# What is the difference between bless and praise in Psalm 145:2?

Tags: psalms

Psalm 145:2
New Living Translation

> I will **praise** you every day; yes, I will **praise** you forever.

English Standard Version

> Every day I will **bless** you and **praise** your name forever and ever.

NLT does not distinguish between bless and praise while ESV does. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry that @ctaylorgraphics deleted his post as it was a good answer.  So I will attempt a second-best answer.

I agree that that the best translation of Ps 145:2 is provided by the ESV and creates a miniature chiasm in a single verse:

> Every day I will bless you
>
> . . . and I will praise Your name for ever and ever

Notice that "bless" corresponds to "praise"; and "every day" corresponds with "for ever and ever"; thus creating the little chiasm.

Now back to the two words of "bless" vs "praise".

Here, "bless" translates בָרַךְ (barak) meaning to kneel or bless; that is to give honor from a subservient position, eg, Gen 24:48, Deut 8:10, Judges 5:2, 9, 1 Chron 29:10, 20, Neh 9:5, etc.

Similarly, "praise" translates הָלַל (halal) [from which which English derives the word, "hallelujah"] and means (literally) to shine.  It is used consistently to mean "praise" (eg, Ps 135:3, 104:35, 106:1, 111:1, etc) or occasionally to boast (ie praising one's self, eg, Ps 44:9, 10:3).

That is, again, the two words are often used as near synonyms as was previously discussed in Ps 104:35.